# Multi Docker Elastic Beanstalk: upload .ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is it possible to deploy .ebextensions to Multi-Docker Elastic Beanstalk?

I use a Dockerrun.aws.json file to upload my App and everything works fine. I want to setup logs to stream to Cloudwatch. I should do that using .ebextensions. However, I don't know how to attach .ebextensions if I upload *in web browser (AWS console)* just only Dockerrun.aws.json (not .zip or .war).

1. How can I deploy also .ebxetensions to Multi Docker Elastic Beanstalk?
2. ... or is it any other way to setup what logs should be streamed to Cloudwatch Logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a zip archive that contains both Dockerrun.aws.json and .ebextensions directory with any configuration files that you require.

Elastic Beanstalk will find Dockerrun.aws.json file from the archive.

This is covered in AWS' [Multicontainer Docker tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecstutorial.html#create_deploy_docker_ecstutorial_deploy).